# Passing and invoking System.Action<> from powershell to c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powershell, speech-recognition

I am working on a c# program using `System.Speech.Recognition` to recognize speech and run PowerShell commands according to what is said.

I have the following powershell script that represents a macro for creating a speech command:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\GAVPI.Lib.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\GAVPI.Lib.Logging.dll"

[Action[GAVPI.Lib.Logging.Parameter]]$speechRecognized = {
    param($i) 
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("test")
}

$parameter = New-Object -TypeName GAVPI.Lib.Logging.Parameter -ArgumentList 
("parameter", "value")

$phrase = New-Object -TypeName GAVPI.Lib.Core.Triggers.Phrase -ArgumentList 
("default","test", $speechRecognized, $parameter)

return $phrase
```

This phrase object is used to tell what commands can be said and recognized.  It successfully is passed to c# like this:

```
 var list = new List<Phrase>();

        var ps = PowerShell.Create();
        var run = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        ps.Runspace = run;
        run.Open();

        var script = ps.AddScript(".\\PowershellTemplate.ps1", true);
        var result = ps.Invoke();

        foreach (var psObject in result)
        {
            if (psObject.BaseObject is Phrase)
            {
                list.Add((Phrase)psObject.BaseObject);
            }
        }
        return list;
```

When a command is recognized,the Phrase class invokes the Action:

```
public override void Run(Parameter selectedparameter)
{

    if (parAction != null)
    {
        parAction.Invoke(selectedparameter);
    }
}
private Action<Parameter> parAction;
```

When the program is run, if you say "test parameter" it invokes the `action<parameter>` in the phrase class, which invokes the script block in powershell.

I get the following exception at the `parAction.Invoke(selectedparameter);` line:

> There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can
>   provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block
>   you attempted to invoke was:
>
> ```
> param($i)...w("test")
> ```

How do I pass the runspace to the `Sysem.Action<Parameter>` so that it can run the PowerShell script block?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?  Is there anything I need to be more clear about?  Perhaps there's a better way of doing this.  Essentially I want to make it easy to write scripts in PowerShell that will allow speech commands to invoke them.

Comment: Did you try and search for that message? Because you should have stumbled over [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx) [two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace(v=vs.85).aspx#Examples)

Comment: Yes, I have looked those sources but the problem is I want to invoke the action in the phrase class that is received from PowerShell.  However, because it came from Powershell, I get the error when trying to invoke it.